# Which language should I specify in .travis.yml?

Tags: python, django, angularjs, travis-ci

I'm in the process of setting up a travis CI server, and am creating my .travis.yml.

My app architecture is a Django backend with an angular frontend, both of which have different dependencies specified.

My question: .travis.yml requires a language to be specified. I could pick either javascript (angular) or python (django). Which should I specify? Is there a way to specify both, and install dependencies for both? I haven't seen anything in the travis docs.

Thanks!

Comment: Node.js is a javascript server, while you said you're using angular on the browser (a client). It really depends on what you want to test.

Comment: What if I want to build my entire app, backend and frontend, and test the whole shebang?